# How to solve the issue "[ERROR] harp-sdk - Cannot pause render loop thread (state=<paused>)"?

Tags: flutter

When I start my App it is running fine and shows the map but if we press the back button and again start the app it just shows a black screen and gives the above error. I am not being able to solve the error. Please help. I am using a here map flutter sdk plugin.

Main.dart :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:here_sdk/core.dart';
import 'package:here_sdk/mapview.dart';

void main() {
SdkContext.init(IsolateOrigin.main);
runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return MaterialApp(
   title: 'HERE SDK for Flutter - Hello Map!',
   home: HereMap(onMapViewCreated: _onMapViewCreated),
 );
 }

 void _onMapViewCreated(MapView mapView) async{
 await mapView.mapScene.loadSceneForMapScheme(MapScheme.normalDay,
        (MapError error) {
      if (error != null) {
        print("Map scene not loaded. MapError: " + error.toString());
      }

      double distanceToEarthInMeters = 8000;
      mapView.camera.lookAtPointWithDistance(
          GeoCoordinates(26.107250, 91.797140), distanceToEarthInMeters);
    });
    }
  }
```